# How to create a faded image using an existing image file

Tags: image-processing, generative-art

The question is simple:

How can I take an image of a perfect stamp (load an image file) such as

[image]

and make it look old, worn, and faded, with missing arbitrary small bits, like the following stamp

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Kuba For me it does not matter if it is a stamp or a photo. All I want is to load an image file (.bmp, .png, .jpg, etc) and remove arbitrary small bits from it, thus making it look old and worn.

Comment: @Kuba Please see my edit!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for being picky :)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Done! Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could try something like this:

with your image,

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf1aj.png"]
```

create some random noise and smooth it, to make the "dirt grains" smoother:

```
noise = ImageAdjust[
  GaussianFilter[RandomImage[{0, 1}, ImageDimensions[img]], 2]]
```

[image]

Then binarize that noise, using MorphologicalBinarize:

```
binary = MorphologicalBinarize[noise, {.6, .7}]
```

[image]

This produces fewer, larger "grains" than simply using Binarize.

Now subtract that image from the alpha channel in your image:

```
SetAlphaChannel[img, ImageSubtract[AlphaChannel[img], binary]]
```

[image]

You can play around with the filter size and the binarization thresholds to get different "graininess":

```
rnd = RandomImage[{0, 1}, ImageDimensions[img]];
Manipulate[
 SetAlphaChannel[img, 
  ImageSubtract[AlphaChannel[img], 
   MorphologicalBinarize[
    ImageAdjust[GaussianFilter[rnd, s]], {t1, t2}]]],
 {{s, 2}, 0, 10}, {{t1, .6}, 0, 1}, {{t2, .7}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Given that your image already has an alpha channel, I would try to reduce the opaque mask on the "stamp" that already exists by multiplying the alpha channel by some selected noise.

Here are a few examples:

`im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf1aj.png"];`

Create flatly random noise in a size half that of the image, then scale. This rescaling reduces pixelation and helps to remove sections rather than just one-off pixels:

`ColorCombine[ColorSeparate[im]*{1, 1, 1, ImageResize[RandomImage[1, {100, 100}], {200, 200}]}, "RGB"]`

[image: alpha x a resized random image]

This one is going to use isolated pixels, but has good contrast since it's using SaltPepper noise:

`ColorCombine[ColorSeparate[im]*{1, 1, 1, ImageEffect[ConstantImage[White, {200, 200}], {"SaltPepperNoise", 1/3}]}, "RGB"]`

[image: SaltPepper holes in the alpha mask]

I think my favorite is a resize of GaussianNoise:

`ColorCombine[ColorSeparate[im]*{1, 1, 1, ImageResize[ImageEffect[   ConstantImage[White, {100, 100}], {"GaussianNoise", 2/3}], Scaled[2]]}, "RGB"]`

[image: Resize a gaussian noise addition to make it look like regions and not just pixels are missing.]

Of course you can play with the noise type and the starting image size to get what matches what you want best.

Comment: When I try the first method with another image I get the following error message: "ColorCombine::ccbinput: should be a list of images with the same image dimensions."

Comment: I also get the same error message when I try the exact same image of the example.

Comment: Hmm. Weird. What does

`ImageDimensions /@ (ColorSeparate[im]*{1, 1, 1,     ImageResize[RandomImage[1, {100, 100}], {200, 200}]})`

say?

Comment: I cannot reproduce neither of the three methods. I tried in v9 and v11 with no luck. In all three of them the `ColorCombine` module complains about the dimensions.

Comment: It sounds like you're on a version before the regular arithmetic functions were extended to images. That's fairly recent.

Comment: The most recent version I have is 11.0.1.0. So what do we do now? Is there a way to modify the proposed methods so as to be compatible with previous versions?

Comment: Try this:

`quietImMult[im1_?ImageQ, im2_] := ImageMultiply[im1, im2]`

`ColorCombine[Thread[quietImMult[ColorSeparate[im], {1, 1, 1, ImageResize[RandomImage[1, {100, 100}], {200, 200}]}]], "RGB"]` .

Comment: Now it's working! So please update your three methods accordingly. BTW what should be changed in case of another image file with dimensions a x b?